# Invertibility of $I + CA^{-1}B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Suppose that $C$ and $B$ are $n \times p$ and $p \times n$, respectively, and that $A + BC$ and $A$ are full rank. Then why is $(I + CA^{-1}B)$ also full rank?

I've tried to manipulate things around, and I wanted to show that 
$(I + CA^{-1}B)x = 0$ implies $x =0$. So far, all I can see is that if $(I + CA^{-1}B)x = 0$, then $(IB + BCA^{-1}B)x = 0$ and thus $(A + BC)(A^{-1}B)x = 0$, so $A^{-1}Bx = 0$ by the non singularity of $A + BC$, and hence $x \in \mathcal{N}(B)$. But that isn't good enough, since $B$ is not full rank.

Comment: If as you proved $Bx=0$ then $(I+CA^{-1}B)x=x+CA^{-1}Bx=x+0=x$. LHS=0 implies RHS=0. Done.

Comment: @A.Γ., indeed xD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [Weinstein-Aronszajn determinant identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weinstein%E2%80%93Aronszajn_identity), since matrices $\rm A$ and $\rm A +  B C$ have full rank,

$$0 \neq \det(\rm A +  B C) = \det (\rm A) \cdot \det (\rm I + A^{-1} B \, C) = \underbrace{\det (\rm A)}_{\neq 0} \cdot \det (\rm I + C \, A^{-1} B)$$

and, thus, $\det (\rm I + C \, A^{-1} B) \neq 0$, i.e., matrix $\rm I + C \, A^{-1} B$ has ful rank.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because I learned something new by reading it. I feel stupid for not seeing the obvious conclusion from $A^{-1}Bx = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

I think you nearly got it.
$(I+CA^{-1}B)x=0$ also implies that $CA^{-1}Bx=-x$. But you got $A^{-1}Bx=0$. I guess you see the problem now.

Comment: Yup, what an idiot I am lol.